# Is there any way to set time to notify?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to set time to notify the user by a flexible time I mean I want to `input` a time.
I can get my desire output with a specific time, but when I input my desired time, It does not go through the program. again ask for `input` time:
I need to print the time and notify and continue the program:

```
20:24:00
  >
```

```
>>> from win10toast import ToastNotifier
>>> import time
>>> def run_app():
>>> show_help()
>>> while True:
>>>     #set time to notify for shopping
>>>     notification_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
>>>     if notification_time == input("Please enter a specific time:\n"):
>>>         print(notification_time)
>>>            
>>>         break
>>>     else:
>>>         pass
>>> #organise the notification
>>> notification1= ToastNotifier()
>>> notification1.show_toast("Alarm","It is time to shop ")
```

the result now is:

```
Please enter a specific time:
20:24:00
Please enter a specific time:
...
```

Comment: Your code requires the user to type six digits, two colons, and hit Enter in less than a second. Can you see why?

Comment: What is the intention of your code? Because right now you have it going in an infinite loop unless the user enters the current time. I have no idea what it's actually supposed to be doing. If you're trying to get the user to enter a time and then wait until that time has passed, you have to at least get their input before you get the time, not to mention that you actually have to wait until that time has passed.

Comment: @RandomDavis
I want at a specific time notify the user to shop
when it notify the user come and enter the shopping list

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I can not understand what you mean?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your input loop is faulty.  It does not at all match what you say you want to do:

```
notification_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
# This stores the current time, mis-named "notification_time"

if notification_time == input("Please enter a specific time:\n"):
# This requires the user to enter a time in the required format.
# If that doesn't match the current time at the previous instruction,
#   you ignore the input and repeat the process.
```

Finally, if the user *does* manage to enter the current time while it is still current, you take that as the notification time.  The user has no way to enter a time in the future.

Instead, you need to accept the user's notification time, and then check that format for validity.  The easiest way is usually to accept the input string, and then use a `try/except` block to convert it to a time.  If that fails you loop back to try the input again.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to make your idea into a functional code:

```
    from datetime import datetime
    import time
    from win10toast import ToastNotifier
    toaster = ToastNotifier()
    # Validate if the format of the time that the user submitted is correct
    def isTimeCorrect(input):
        try:
            time.strptime(input, '%H:%M:%S')
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return print('time is wrong')
    # Request the user to type the alarm time
    alarm = input('Type your alarm time in this format HH:MM:SS\n')
    # Get the current time
    now = datetime.now()
    # Format the current time
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    # Loop and check the current time until it's the same as the alarm
    while (isTimeCorrect(alarm)):
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        # Check if the current time is the same as the alarm
        if current_time == alarm:
            # throw the notification
            toaster.show_toast("Example","Notifcation Text",icon_path=None,duration=5,threaded=True)
            break
```